# AVAudioSession Not Working on Certain Bluetooth Devices

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, avaudiosession

I'm having issues with Bluetooth playback but only on certain bluetooth devices. Other apps work fine on these same bluetooth devices. Am I missing something with the way I'm setting the category for my `AVAudioSession`?

```
    let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, with: [.defaultToSpeaker, .allowBluetooth, .allowAirPlay])
        try session.setActive(true)

        session.requestRecordPermission({(granted:Bool) in
            if granted {
                Variables.appHasMicAccess = true
            } else {
                Variables.appHasMicAccess = false
            }
        })
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("AVAudioSession configuration error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
```

### Update

Solution was to add an additional option `.allowBluetoothA2DP`. This was introduced in iOS 10.

> Starting with iOS 10.0, apps using the playAndRecord category may also allow routing output to paired Bluetooth A2DP devices. To enable this behavior, you need to pass this category option when setting your audio session's category.

More details [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/categoryoptions/1771735-allowbluetootha2dp)

Comment: What exactly is the issue you're facing? Is the device headset or speaker? Does it support A2DP or only HFP (if its headset)

Comment: @Sunil the devices are speakers not headsets. It does support A2DP. The issue is that some bluetooth devices (random ones, haven't identified a pattern yet) don't play audio from my app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the playback is on a speaker which uses A2DP, considering setting the session like this:

```
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
do {
      try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, 
           mode: AVAudioSessionModeVideoRecording,
           options: [.defaultToSpeaker, .allowAirPlay, .allowBluetoothA2DP])
      try audioSession.setActive(true)
} catch let error {
      print("audioSession properties weren't set!", error)
}
```

Notice the option ".allowBluetoothA2DP"

Hope that helps

Comment: I was missing the `.allowBluetoothA2DP` and `setActive(true)` in my case, and the headphones were only showing if they were already connected when I ran the code. Very confusing. Anyway, this helped.